# Shortcut Key on Access Form Command Button with Image

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

Is it possible to assign a shortcut key to a command button on an MS Access Form that is set to an image?

In this case, I have an unbound form, I would like to setup basic record navigation with the familiar CTRL + Arrow Keys. For my case, when a user wants to go to the next record, I would like them to be able to simply press CTRL + RIGHT ARROW as an option to a mouse click.

I'm aware for text captions, you simply insert an "&" before the desired shortcut character for example: `"&Next"`

[image: Button Next Sample]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

& also works on picture buttons even caption is not visible, but if you want to use not only Alt-letter shortcuts, you can use form level `KeyDown` or `KeyPress` events for this. Enable `KeyPreview` property first.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case vbKeyF2
            ' Process F2 key events.
        Case vbKeyF3
            ' Process F3 key events.
        Case vbKeyF4
            ' Process F4 key events.
        Case Else
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Can we use combination of keypress? i.e. `Ctrl + W` or `Ctrl + SpaceBar`?

Comment: Yes, `Shift` parameter contains information about key modifiers (Shift, Ctrl, Alt)